# Is there a way to develop and execute python code in azure function directly in azure portal?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-async

I'm looking for developing and execute python code directly in azure portal but
[But I can only see the .Net,Java and Node js where I can get the Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpeFW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Python Functions can be deployed through the CLI. Python requires more investment to support streaming logs, installation of third-party packages, etc. so we decided to de-emphasize it for now. The plan is to bring a first-class experience back in the future. Exact timeline TBD

Answer (score 0):

You could not get Python cause you choose wrong `OS`, you need choose **Linux**, then `Python(preview)` will show in the Runtime Stack.

[image]

However the feature about editing the Python Function is disabled, so you could only develop the function local and update it to Azure.

[image]